# Retrieve timestamp from datetime instantiated with utcfromtimestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp, python-3.6

In a Python script I instantiated a `datetime` with a timestamp value.
I fail to retrieve the original timestamp.

Example:

```
origin_timestamp = 1554840000
utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(origin_timestamp)
calculated_timestamp = utc_datetime.timestamp()
print("===== calculated_timestamp =====")
print(calculated_timestamp)

print("===== EQUAL TIMESTAMP =====")
print(origin_timestamp == calculated_timestamp)
```

Display the following lines in CLI :

```
===== calculated_timestamp =====
1554829200.0
===== EQUAL TIMESTAMP =====
False
```

I don't find anything in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to get the timestamp. Do you know a way to retrieve my origin timestamp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is naive `datetime` instances are assumed to represent local time, which affects what the `timestamp()` method does. You can fix that by making a timezone-aware utc `datetime` instance by calling:

```
utc_datetime.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Here's a full example:

```
import datetime


origin_timestamp = 1554840000

print("===== origin_timestamp =====")
print(origin_timestamp)

utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(origin_timestamp)
print("===== utc_datetime =====")
print(utc_datetime)

# Add a timezone to utc_datetime
utc_datetime2 = utc_datetime.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
print("===== utc_datetime2 =====")
print(utc_datetime2)

# Use it.
calculated_timestamp = utc_datetime2.timestamp()
print("===== calculated_timestamp =====")
print(calculated_timestamp)

print("===== difference =====")
print(calculated_timestamp - origin_timestamp)

print("===== EQUAL TIMESTAMP =====")
print(origin_timestamp == calculated_timestamp)
```

Output:

```
===== origin_timestamp =====
1554840000
===== utc_datetime =====
2019-04-09 20:00:00
===== utc_datetime2 =====
2019-04-09 20:00:00+00:00
===== calculated_timestamp =====
1554840000.0
===== difference =====
0.0
===== EQUAL TIMESTAMP =====
True
```

**FYI:** The major clue that helped me figure what was going on was by printing the difference between the two timestamps, which was `25200` seconds — exactly `7.0` hours — something that seemed quite a bit like a timezone offset from UTC (here in the US anyway). The documentation for [`datatime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) confirms that this is what the instance method does.

Here's what I mean:

```
>>> m = 25200 / 60  # difference in minutes
>>> m
420.0
>>> h = m / 60  # in hours
>>> h
7.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I could ignore timezone because I don't specify one during instanciation but datetime implicit define one (based on OS I supposed). Thank you for solution.

Comment: jedema: It's because `timestamp()` uses the platform C library `mktime()` function, which is defined to convert a local time to the time since epoch — so it's locale, not OS, dependent. BTW, in English, the spelling is "instantiation" not "instanciation" (although it's [pronounced](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/instantiation?s=t) that way).